# Cocoapods runs indefinitely

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I installed cocoapods and was trying to install my first pod after creating `Podfile`
But pod runs indefinitely

```
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb:55: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
```

Even `pod repo remove master` or `pod setup` also result in same message

--Update 04-Mar-2013 11:08 AM IST--

The warning has been gone after changing permissions. Thanks for Thomas' comments. But the endless wait isn't over. I get the following message for any actions I do with pod. I am running ruby 2.0

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.4.1]

$ pod repo remove master --verbose

Setting up CocoaPods master repo

Cloning spec repo `master` from `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` (branch `master`)
  $ /usr/local/bin/git clone 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' master
  Cloning into 'master'...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your /usr/local path is not writable.

Try `(sudo)chmod go-w /usr/local` in terminal.

When that command finishes, retry your Podfile installation

EDIT:

When it says `"Cloning into 'master'..."`, it means that Cocoapods is cloning a git repository. (in your case: the Cocoapods Specs repository). Cocoapods does this only the first time you use Cocoapods (when pod setup is executed).
The only thing you have to do is wait (could take a while depending on your internet connection (it's becoming a fairly large repository, so it would take a while).

So, what I would do, to reset your cocoapods installation:

1. In Finder: navigate to hidden folder: ~/.cocoapods/repos (
   this is where cocoapods secretly clones its master specs repository)
2. There, you'll find a folder called "master" ==> remove it
3. Then in terminal, you execute `pod setup` (which initialises Cocoapods and starts cloning to specs repository again)

Comment: the warning has been gone and hit by another error issue. Updated my original question

Comment: Thanks for the update. I am doing it now. I am wondering why pod --help even wants to setup repo. Quite strange.